# Load new Tab dynamically with own FXMLs

Tags: java, dynamic, javafx, tabs, fxml

I want to write an application, that has got a few options. The user can choose in a menu one option and a tab should be created, which loads its view from another fxml-file(, which has also another view-controller). Currently my code looks like:

```
Tab t = new Tab("My New Tab");
try {
    t.setClosable(true);
    t.setId("test");
    t.setContent(FXMLLoader.
      load(getClass().
        getResource("/package/NewTabView.fxml")));
} catch (Exception e) {

}

tabPane.getTabs().add(t);
selectionModel.selectLast();
```

Hope you can help me, because I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Actually which line throws the exception? My guess is "load(getClass().
        getResource("/package/NewTabView.fxml")));". Where do your file is located? Because now it indicates that you are storing it at "<project_root>\package\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like what @DVarga said you need to check the location of your `NewTabView.fxml` file.

Here is an example that could help you:

- Here we have two FXML files with their controller classes
- The `firstView` FXML file is the one that contains the `TabPane`
- The `secondView` FXML file contains the content that we are going to load dynamically inside a new `Tab` in the first `TabPane`
- Nothing fancy in the MainApp class, we are just loading the firstView and setting its controller
- The interesting thing goes in the `createTabDynamically()` method where we load the FXML file of the `secondView` and set its controller, then we instantiate a new tab and set the secondView as its content and we finally add it to the `TabPane`.

**FirstView.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="container" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="closeMI" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="openTabMI" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open the new tab" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="ALL_TABS">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="myTab" closable="false" text="MyTab">
               <content>
                  <VBox>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Hello From the first view" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**SecondView.FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<VBox fx:id="container" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="secondInfoLbl" text="This is the second view">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

**FirstViewController.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class FirstViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private MenuItem openTabMI, closeMI;
    @FXML private TabPane tabPane;
    private Tab myDynamicTab;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        openTabMI.setOnAction((event)->{
            createTabDynamically();
        });

        closeMI.setOnAction((event)->{Platform.exit();});
    }

    private void createTabDynamically() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("secondView.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new SecondViewController());
        try {
            Parent parent = loader.load();
            myDynamicTab = new Tab("A Dynamic Tab");
            myDynamicTab.setClosable(true);
            myDynamicTab.setContent(parent);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(myDynamicTab);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**SecondViewController.java**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SecondViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Label secondInfoLbl;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        secondInfoLbl.setText("Hello from the second view");
    }
}
```

**MainApp.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FirstView.fxml"));
        FirstViewController firstViewController = new FirstViewController();
        loader.setController(firstViewController);
        Parent parent = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```